# nginx rewrite does not work?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Rewrite url nginx does not work?

```
location /opensource {
  rewrite ^/opensource/ckeditor/plugins/smiley/images/([a-zA-Z0-9_-_.]+)$ /application/views/js/ckeditor/plugins/smiley/images/$1;
}
```

Any help?

Comment: How do you know that it does not work?

Comment: My guess, that you even don't need rewrite here, just `alias`.

Comment: Part `_-_` is very weird. What's the expected behaviour ? Give an example at least.